# How to intigrations sealpayment getways in php

Tags: php

How to integration  ICICI payment gateway I getting something error and not clearly understand so pls help me.

Comment: did you not get any documentation or integration files?

Answer (score 0):

```
1:- Read carefully ICICI Payment gateway manual Installing_PHP_SFA_Without_Java_Bridge.doc file URL: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0_uOdtbSi9mak4yMEtRX1prSm8/edit?usp=sharing 
2:- Testssl.php example.

<?php
include("Sfa/BillToAddress.php");
include("Sfa/CardInfo.php");
include("Sfa/Merchant.php");
include("Sfa/MPIData.php");
include("Sfa/ShipToAddress.php");
include("Sfa/PGResponse.php");
include("Sfa/PostLibPHP.php");
include("Sfa/PGReserveData.php");

$oMPI           =   new MPIData();
$oCI            =   new CardInfo();
$oPostLibphp    =   new PostLibPHP();
$oMerchant      =   new Merchant();
$oBTA           =   new BillToAddress();
$oSTA           =   new ShipToAddress();
$oPGResp        =   new PGResponse();
$oPGReserveData =   new PGReserveData();

$oMerchant->setMerchantDetails("00003875","00003875","00003875","10.10.10.238",rand()."","Ord1234","http://localhost/merchant/SFAResponse.php","POST","INR","INV123","req.Sale","100","","Ext1","true","Ext3","Ext4","New PHP");

$oBTA->setAddressDetails ("CID","Tester","Aline1","Aline2","Aline3","Pune","A.P","48927489","IND","tester@soft.com");

$oSTA->setAddressDetails ("Add1","Add2","Add3","City","State","443543","IND","sad@df.com");

#$oMPI->setMPIRequestDetails("1245","12.45","356","2","2 shirts","12","20011212","12","0","","image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/msword, application/x-shockwave-flash, */*","Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0)");
$oMPI->setMPIRequestDetails("1245","12.45","356","2","2 shirts","12","20011212","12","0","","image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/msword, application/x-shockwave-flash, */*","Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT 5.0)");

$oPGResp=$oPostLibphp->postSSL($oBTA,$oSTA,$oMerchant,$oMPI,$oPGReserveData);

if($oPGResp->getRespCode() == '000'){
    $url    =$oPGResp->getRedirectionUrl();
    #$url =~ s/http/https/;
    #print "Location: ".$url."\n\n";
    #header("Location: ".$url);
    redirect($url);
}else{
    print "Error Occured.<br>";
    print "Error Code:".$oPGResp->getRespCode()."<br>";
    print "Error Message:".$oPGResp->getRespMessage()."<br>";
}

# This will remove all white space
#$oResp =~ s/\s*//g;
# $oPGResp->getResponse($oResp);
#print $oPGResp->getRespCode()."<br>";
#print $oPGResp->getRespMessage()."<br>";
#print $oPGResp->getTxnId()."<br>";
#print $oPGResp->getEpgTxnId()."<br>";

function redirect($url) {
    if(headers_sent()){
    ?>
        <html><head>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                window.self.location='<?php print($url);?>';
            </script>
        </head></html>
    <?php
        exit;
    } else {
        header("Location: ".$url);
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```